# Android - App starts but doesn't load on debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, launch, breakpoints

When running my app on debug mode, I see the "Connecting debugger" dialog, but after it's gone - I see a black screen and nothing happens.

I put a breakpoint on the first line of the onCreate() method of my startup activity, but the the control never reaches the breakpoint!

When launching the app through the launcher app on my phone, it starts up normally

Any suggestions as to what can be the cause of this?
**Phone**: Samsung Vibrant i9000
**ROM**: CyanogenMod7.1
**Android Ver.**:2.3.7

Comment: What does the console say on the last line after it is started?

Comment: The console says: [2012-01-15 16:35:28 - AppName] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.../.Splash }  
  ,
Logcat doesn't show any message from the system.

Comment: Some phones require a special driver (not the normal adb driver) to be able to debug on the phone. Have you debugged any apps on this phone?

Comment: I did debug my app before on my phone, but I still do now, but 70% of the time the debug mode doesn't load... That's why it's so weird - it's pretty much random whether it works or not.

Comment: One issue that I have sometimes is that the debugger will not work sometimes unless I uninstall the app from the phone manually, first. Also, if I keep the phone on too long or Eclipse open too long, I have to restart one or the other of them. (phone over 3 hours, Eclipse over 24 hours). But that's just my system.